# The code execution cannot proceed because tensorflow.dll was not found

Tags: c, tensorflow

I am testing the prebuilt CPU version of [Tensorflow C_api](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) for Windows (windows 10)

My project structure is:

```bash
DIR |
    |include-+
    |        |tensorflow+
    |                   | c
    |                   | core
    |
    |lib-----+
    |        |tensorflow.dll
    |        |tensorflow.lib
    |    
    |test_tf-+
             |hello_tf.c
```

Example program: `hello_tf.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation to `.exe`:

```
gcc -IC:\...path..to...\include -LC:\...path..to...\lib hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf
```

This generates a `hello_tf.exe`, shows this error when run:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because tensorflow.dll was not found. 
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

Any solutions?

**EDIT:**
Temporary solution: Place the `.dll` in the same folder as the generated `.exe`

```bash
DIR |
    |include-+
    |        |tensorflow+
    |                   | c
    |                   | core
    |
    |lib-----+
    |        |tensorflow.lib
    |    
    |test_tf-+
             |hello_tf.c
             |hello_tf.exe  (generated during compilation)
             |tensorflow.dll
```

Can someone kindly point me to an example of linking this kind of `.dll`...without placing it in the same folder?

Comment: Did you put the DLL in one of your dynamic library search paths? If you're not prepared to handle dynamic linking issues, just static link and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. This helps as a quick fix, although can you link some examples of dynamic linking?

Comment: The problem with dynamic linking is it complicates the installation procedure, so if you can avoid it, it's best you do. If you do want to use the DLL approach, you'll need to create an installer, and you'll also need to find out how to tweak the compiled program's search path to include this installation location, which the installer may allow the user to define.

Comment: holycow. that is pointlessly complex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ8Dp3nYmpM&ab_channel=DanielDuan

Comment: Dynamic libraries are a mixed bag. In a really well curated environment they can do what they promised, that is be shared across multiple applications. In practice, though, you often have dozens of copies of slightly different versions of the library installed here, there and everywhere. How many copies of DirectX do you have on your Windows machine, for example? To keep things simple, go static. You have a larger executable file, but it's much less likely to break because of weird dependency issues.